# When not supplying a Mandatory parameter make the prompt not interpret it as a string

Tags: powershell

I have a mandatory parameter like:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$foo
```

I do want PowerShell to prompt to supply one if the user failed to do so. However, I would like to be able to supply a variable; that is if `$bar` is supplied, it does not bind it as `$foo = "$bar"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `ExpandString` function to expand that variable like:

```
function Test-Param
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$foo
    )

    $foo = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($foo)

    Write-Host $foo   
}
```

You can test it using:

```
$bar = "hello"
Test-Param
```

Now just pass `$bar` to the prompt and you will get  `hello` printed.

Comment: Excellent; I have never seen that before.

Comment: @briantist It is very useful when working with a here-string

Comment: Couldn't you use the double-quoted here-string for that? `@"..."@` Or am I misunderstanding the usage you're referring to?

Comment: Yeah, I mean if you define the here-string at the top of your script using `@' .... '@` and you obtain the variables later, then you can expand the variables.